# Polymer 1.0 <template> tag not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I lifted the most basic example from the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration), and it seems that the `<template>` tag is not working. Nothing is rendered within the `<register-me>` tag mounted in the document:

[image: inspector view of mounted register-me]

Expected: "Hello from my local DOM"

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Polymer 1.0.6 test</title>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.10/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/v1.0.6/polymer-mini.html">
    </head>
    <body>
      
    <dom-module id="register-me">
      <template>
        <div>Hello from my local DOM</div>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({is: "register-me"});
      </script>
    </dom-module>
      
    <register-me></register-me>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Live: http://jsbin.com/qijegu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Polymer Micro, which does not include template stamping. It is included in Polymer Mini, however ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/experimental.html#polymer-mini)).

**Edit**

If you want to define elements in your main document, you need to listen to the HTMLImports.whenReady event. Otherwise, it will not work in some browsers. This is explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#main-document-definitions).

```
HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
     Polymer({is: "register-me"});
});
```

Comment: Switched to polymer-mini, which works in Chrome 44 but not Firefox 40.